# Can we improve x-ray telescopes by a factor of 100,000 with better image sensors?

Tags: telescopes

As long as the image sensor`s pixels are smaller than the imaging system's point spread function, they don't influence it.

However, if we look at the Hubbel telescope, it has an NA of 1/48, making its main lobe of the PSF have a diameter of 24λ, which is 13 µm for the green light and 0.1-100 nm for x-rays.

Given that the Hubbel telescope uses 15 µm CCD sensors, it's x-raying resolution can be improved by up to 100,000 if we could improve its image sensor to have a 0.1 nm pixel size.

Such improvement, of course, not realistic with CCD technology. But we can produce today [7 nm chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excimer_laser#Photolithography) using a Photolithography process. Maybe it will be possible to use this technology with image sensors.

Putting aside the challenge of making a 0.1 nm image sensor, how realistic is this idea? Are there other factors that will make this impossible?

Comment: Just to clarify, Hubble is not an X-ray telescope. Are you asking about Hubble or about an X-ray telescope like XMM-Newton?

Comment: @kaylimekay The question is about the idea of using a better image sensor to get a better resolution. I saw that XMM-Newton also using CCD, so I guess it has the same pixel size as Hubble. Do you know what its NA value?

Comment: I am not sure, sorry.